# subir una imagen en PHP y guardar el resultado en base de datos

Tags: php, mysqli

Intenté subir una foto de perfil mediante este código en `php` y pues lo guarda en la ruta que yo especifique pero no guarda nada en la base de datos. Estoy trabajando con `wampserver` y `phpmyadmin`.

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
$imagen = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
$ruta = "../subidos/" . $_FILES['imagen']['name']; 
$resultado = @move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"], $ruta); 


 $modificar=("UPDATE usuario SET nombre = '".$nombre."', pass= '".$password."', 
              escolar = '".$nivel."',nacimiento='".$fecha2."',foto_perfil='".$image."'
             WHERE CodUsua='".$_SESSION["CodUsua"]."'");
```

Comment: En que momento declaras la variable `$image`, creo que deberia de ir `$imagen` en el UPDATE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu código esta bien. Según puedo ver, el error esta en esta parte

```
foto_perfil='".$image."'
```

Estas escribiendo "$image" y segun leo, tu variable se llama "$imagen". Tu consulta deberia quedar asi:

```
$modificar=("UPDATE usuario SET nombre = '".$nombre."', pass= '".$password."', 
          escolar = '".$nivel."',nacimiento='".$fecha2."',foto_perfil='".$imagen."'
         WHERE CodUsua='".$_SESSION["CodUsua"]."'");
```

Y gracias a la colaboracion de JackNavaRow, en el futuro, si quieres mostrar esa imagen al usuario o alguien mas puedes usar:

```
<img src="miruta/<?=$imagen?>">
```

Comment: una última consulta como puedo mostrar esa foto de perfil que subi

Comment: Si he respondido tu pregunta, no olvides marcarla como respuesta, te lo agradeceria. Con respecto a como mostrar esa foto, pues con la etiqueta <img> en html puedes mostrarla solo indicando la ruta. Si tienes preguntas mas especificas de esto, puedes iniciar otra pregunta. Saludos!

Comment: <img src="miruta/<?=$imagen?>">

Comment: Gracias @JackNavaRow, queria incentivarlo a que fuera curioso hahaha. Carlos esa es la respuesta. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Donde pretendes guardar la foto de perfil en la base de datos? En el campo "foto_perfil" ?

Si es asi, lo que te recomiendo que hagas en el update es que guardes la ruta en ese campo: $ruta. Asi cuando vayas a cargar desde la BBDD la foto de perfil solo en el fetch solo tienes que poner el

Comment: si así se llama el campo ... y ya me guardo ahora tengo problemas para mostrar esa foto

Comment: esta respuesta no es valida te recomiendo borrarla o modificarla

Comment: JackNavaRow por que no va a ser util? yo lo tengo asi en la mayoria de sitios y sigue funcionando...

$resultado = mysql_query("SELECT id, nombre FROM mitabla");

<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
{
?>                        
  <tr>      
    <td><img src="<?php echo row['url']; ?>"/></td>
  </tr>
<?php
}

?>

Comment: Creo que este ultimo comentario debe ir en el cuerpo de la respuesta, recuerda que Stackoverflow en Español no funciona igual que otros sitios de la red :)